# Bootstrap navbar not opening or collapsing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm looking for a collapsible navbar. I attempted it with the code below without any success.

The following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Portfolio</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">        </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- nav bar -->
<nav style="background-color:#ffaa00" class="navbar navbar-light navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Portfolio Site</a>
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-        toggle="collapse" data-target=".navigation"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-                    menu-hamburger"></span></button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navigation">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: You need to place _[jQuery](https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included)_ before Bootstrap.js and (maybe a typo) but `data-        toggle="collapse"` needs to be `data-toggle="collapse"`, no spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed ,

```
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

within your button tag. Also make sure to add correct bootstrap and Jquery CDNs

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Portfolio</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- nav bar -->
<nav style="background-color:#ffaa00" class="navbar navbar-light navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Portfolio Site</a>
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navigation"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span></button>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navigation">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Do I need the icon-bar span tags being that I have the glyphicon version?